# Why does ggplot give a blank page with the message "Regions defined for each Polygons"?

Tags: r, ggplot2

After reading a shapefile, I am using `plot()`, and am getting a plot.

But when I am using `q=ggplot()`, am getting a blank plot along with the message

> Regions defined for each Polygons

Any idea why?

Comment: Do you just type ggplot() and that's it?

Comment: I have tried using qplot(), too. as in, qplot(the file read)

Comment: Post the actual code you've used.  No offense but we can't trust that you've done anything correctly if you don't show us what you actually did.

Comment: Perhaps you should read [ggplot2: plotting polygon shapefiles](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/wiki/plotting-polygon-shapefiles). The shape file must be turned into a data.frame `ggplot` is not a generic function in the way `plot` is that can translate a bunch of different class types into plots. It really only knows about data.frames.

Comment: thanks, I think I found the answer. we have to use fortify() for plotting shapefiles using ggplot.

Comment: @user2458552 Why don't you go ahead and post that as an answer and accept it to close out the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use fortify() to plot shapefiles using ggplot.